# Does iPhone support audio in via dock connector

Tags: iphone, dock

Fisrt , sorry my bad English
I'd like to play audio on iPhone / iPod via dock connector
the model is audio in from dock to iPhone, and audio out from iPhone
is't possible

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know, you cannot use iPhone this way.

Comment: For clarification, it does support audio, but not in the way he wants.

Comment: so, the iPhone only support audio out to the dock?
doesn't supprot aduio in via dock / connector?

Comment: Your question made it sound like you wanted audio in on the dock and audio out on the headphone jack -- at the same time.

Comment: Yes, at the same time. Possible?